# Delete rows in database laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i want delete all information for one user in database if there is already information.

```
$ss= date_time::where('user_id',$id)->get();
        if ($ss){
            $ss->delete();
  }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Do you have a model named `date_time`?

Comment: ok, and where is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$ss` will be a collection so you either need to delete every individual item or do a single delete without a get:

```
 $ss= date_time::where('user_id',$id)->get();
 $ss->each(function ($model) { 
     $model->delete();
 });
 // or
 date_time::where('user_id',$id)->delete();
```

The first way is slower but will trigger model events like `deleting` and `deleted` while the second one is much faster but will not trigger any events.

Comment: Wow, you answered 3 seconds before me, but I guess, first come, first served, so I deleted my answer

Comment: @MartinDimitrov Your answer is a valid answer and there's no reason why there should only be one answer to a question and both answers were given practically at the same time so there's  no argument for plagiarism

Comment: Yes, but your answer has more information and is overall better, so I will keep it deleted.